# Bike trainer skewer does not fully seat into depth of mounting cup, is that an issue?

Tags: trainer, skewer

I bought a used trainer and it came with a trainer skewer. I don't know if it's the original from the trainer.

I've put in the trainer skewer and have mounted my bike to the trainer.
However, I noticed that the skewer ends don't go all the way into the cup at the mounting points. It's most noticeable on the side with the quick release.

[image: trainer skewer mounting points]

You'll notice that the cup even has cut outs on both sides for the quick release lever, but the qr stem end is only half way in.

Should I be concerned? I've done a couple of training sessions and the bike was totally stable.

Comment: Does the head of the QR go into the cup all the way if the QR is not fitted to the bike? Does it touch the bottom of the cup?

Comment: I suspect that QR is not the right one for that trainer.

Comment: When he skewer is not in the bike the wrong end does not fit into the cup.

Comment: It looks like a Tacx Trainer, I'll dig out my QR later after work but I'm sure you position the cup to go over the lever with the cut out recess, you should be able to rotate the trainer cups

Comment: I wonder if you were given the wrong skewer.

Comment: @Dan_K: I rotated the cup so that the qr and the other end of the qr handle fit into the two notches. But it can’t slide that far

Comment: Is it safe to use what I currently have? The bike is stable while I’m training.

Comment: The fit in the above image is probably OK.  The bigger question is how it fits on the other side, and whether wear on the skewer end may eventually fail.

Comment: @DanK : you’re right that it’s a Tacx skewer. My trainer is from Kinetic. I guess the Tacx skewer just doesn’t fit.

Comment: Great work coming back and sharing your result.  Would you be able to post the answer as an answer, down below?  This keeps the Q and A separate and works better.  Otherwise this question shows up as "unanswered"   SE totally permits self-answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought a new skewer for my trainer...the one the manufacturer sells. The two ends fit nicely into the cup.

[image: qr skewer]
[image: skewer other end with washers]

You’ll notice that I had to stack 3 washers in the other end. The skewer was poking out the other end too much and the cup would not seat all the way in.

[image: washers for spacing]

Comment: Will the washers be okay? Doesn’t seem like it will be an issue.